# iPhone: Where is my Sqlite database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can't find my SQLite DB. I'm using the 4.1 simulator.

All the tutorials say it's at `/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/<APP>/Documents`. There's nothing there. How do I create a new one by code? So that I see a `.sqlite` file here?

In my code I am doing this:

```
int result = sqlite3_open("/MyApp.db", &database);

if(result != SQLITE_OK)
{
sqlite3_close(database);
NSLog(@"Failed to open DB");
return;
}

else {
NSLog(@"Opened DB");
}
```

I then proceed to create a table, and query from it and both of them succeed.

Yet, I can't find the sqlite file it's putting the data at.

Where could it possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below there are 2 function

1. First one to copy you database if it is not in your app during installing in ur emulator.

2.second function to get the path of database.

these 2 functions must call in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` delegate function in `yourAppdelegate.m` 
 so that your database will copy it into your application folder of the emulator if it not present there.

Don't forget to add

```
NSString *databasePath;
sqlite3 *contactDB;
```

in `yourAppdelegate.h`

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *dbPath = [PropertyUploaderAppDelegate getDBPath];

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success) 

    {

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 

stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOURDATABASENAME.sqlite"];

success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)

            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }

}


+(NSString *) getDBPath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOURDATABASENAME.sqlite"];

}
```

After these process
check it in `/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.1/Applications/<yourAppfolder>/Documents`

Comment: Looks potentially a good answer, but needs editing.  I almost did it myself but I couldn't quite work out what you were intending, and in any case I don't have editing privileges so it would have gone for review first.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't put in app delegate but directly before the code where I connect to DB... It's giving me "Failed to create with message The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"... So the DB file doesn't even exist in the default path?

Comment: Hisoka, you need to create a database using firefox addon(sqlite) after that you need to copy that database in your app and add to the resource folder of your app. Then specify you db name in that code .I hope you import <sqlite3.h> in your files you used.

Comment: Where is the resources folder? I keep getting stuck 'cause that folder keeps getting references in all tutorials, yet I do not see it in XCode 4. Also, do I specify the entire filename like db.sqlite as the db name?

Comment: Hisoka Resource folder is standard concept which separate our own files such as images,db etc from other files. So we just create a new group(folder named Resource).and drag ur db in this folder. In code you don't specify foldername or anything. You just specify your dbname.sqlite.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Wow... I used Core Data yesterday, then when I tried to migrate it screwed things up, so ended up using Sqlite, then wasted hours on getting that to work. Now, it finally works! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save in the app's directory then do this,

```
NSString *dirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbFile = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sqlite.db"];
```

If you are opening a file `/MyApp.db`, then it will be at the root of your Mac. Open the `Macintosh HD` in Finder to see if it is there.

Comment: Great.. now the file is being copied to this folder.. But now I created the tables, inserted some data, all successful (as I did a select at the end, and see it), yet it's not being saved to this database file! The file is 0 KB.... Any idea why? I'm finalizing my prepared statements, and even did a commit for safety. Yet, no data!

Comment: SQLite3 buffers writes. The data should arrive on disk eventually.